Application works but "Could not find or load main class" when launching jar
It's time for one of the theoretically most basic question ! I tried all classic and simple solutions and I'm running out of ideas.
So, my App works well when I launch it directly in my IDE but when I try to execute the fatJar (with a classical java -jar locationOfJar) I get the traditionnal "Error: Could not find or load main class w.x.y.z.App"
What I tried :

I quadruple checked that my main class is well defined in my build.gradle.kts (I give parts later) I even wrote this post with real copy/paste and changed all with "replace" to check if they are really the same name

I unzipped my jar and checked that the main-class is there with the right name

in the unzipped jar I checked that every import of the main-class is present

I verified that the .jar contains a META-INF/MANIFEST.MF, it contains 2 lines : Manifest-Version: 1.0 and Main-Class: w.x.y.z.App

when I try to run the jar (and not the fatJar) I get the error "no main manifest attribute" while the manifest is there too !


I'm sure it's a stupid mistake but I can't find it ! Do you have an idea ?
My build.gradle.kts :
plugins {
  id("java")
}

java {
  sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

tasks.register<Jar>("fatJar") {
  group = "build"
  archiveClassifier.set("all")
  from(sourceSets.main.get().output)

  dependsOn(configurations.runtimeClasspath)
  from({
    configurations.runtimeClasspath.get().map { if (it.isDirectory) it else zipTree(it) }
  })

  manifest {
    attributes["Main-Class"] = "w.x.y.z.App"
  }
  duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
}

dependencies {
...
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  maven {
    name = "Artifact"
    url = uri(project.findProperty("mavenRepositoryUrl") as String)
    credentials {
      username = project.findProperty("mavenRepositoryUsername") as String
      password = project.findProperty("mavenRepositoryPassword") as String
    }
  }
}

Start of App Class :
package w.x.y.z;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import ...

public class App {

  LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    LOG.info("===== START =====");
    ... 
  }
}


App.class must be in the w/x/y/z folder hierarchy (w must be under the root of the JAR) - also try java -cp file.jar w.x.y.z.App

@user85421 w is well at the root of the jar and java -cp file.jar w.x.y.z.App returns the same error (Error: Could not find or load main class w.x.y.z.App)

shouldn't it be public class App ?

@GyroGearless That's true ! But I corrected it and it changes nothing. I edit the post

Copy the command line and error literally from the command line, with all lines, as text, as paste it in your question using [code block] format.

"same Error", no more details? OK, w is at root, and App.class in w/x/y/z ? (since these are fictive folders, be sure they are all correctly spelled)

@Marce - the error message posted in the question "Error: Could not find or load main class w.x.y.z.App" shows that dots are being used; the author confirmed "I verified that the .jar contains a META-INF/MANIFEST.MF, it contains 2 lines : Manifest-Version: 1.0 and Main-Class: w.x.y.z.App", with dots; even the Gradle file shows attributes["Main-Class"] = "w.x.y.z.App" - where did you get the "Main-Class: wxyzApp" from? ((is your browser having problems with the dots? I see all the dots in this my comment, no need for underscores))

@usuario85421, I just found out that I have a problem in my browser, I see it without dots, I'll try to change it... thanks for informing me!!!

For those wondering, the problem was solved by adding "exclude("META-INF/.SF", "META-INF/.DSA", "META-INF/*.RSA")" in the tasks.register("fatJar")
I was using a dependency that generated those kind of files next to the manifest and that was making the mess
